# Updated OpenSSH From Source, Now sshd_config Is Not Applying Directives

Tags: linux, centos, ssh

I updated the openssh package to version 5.9p2 from source so I can use conditional statements. Running CentOS 5.6 x86.

```
OpenSSH_5.9p2, OpenSSL 0.9.8e-fips-rhel5 01 Jul 2008
```

The problem even though `ssh -v` shows the correct version, when I modify `/etc/ssh/sshd_config` directives don't seem to take effect. I can even type incorrect syntax in the sshd_config file, just utter gibberish, and when I do `service sshd restart` I don't see the syntax errors listed.

Am I missing something here?

Comment: When you compiled OpenSSH and `make install`, where did the binaries go ? Are you sure you are calling the one that you compiled ? `updatedb` then `locate sshd` and `locate sshd_config`. If you didn't pay enough attention to `configure` options, it could be using the config file from somewhere else (i.e. /usr/local/sshd/etc).

Comment: Yeah when I compiled I did: `./configure --prefix=/usr && make && make install` should I change that too: `./configure --prefix=/etc && make && make install`

Comment: Rebuild using the correct --prefix or other configure variables so it is in the normal location.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you `configure` using only `--prefix=/usr`, it meant that everything got installed into `/usr` (binaries, configuration, etc.)

If you like to compile things, it is a good practice to **always** read `configure --help` first. It will give you hints on how defaults are setup.

Comment: After about 8 tries (sigh), I think this the right configure syntax to override the default CentOS openssh. `./configure --exec-prefix= --prefix=/usr --sysconfdir=/etc/ssh && make && make install`